# Does it violate any normalization rules if I add a boolean column to a db table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-normalization

Database tables:

Servers

| Id | ServerType |
| --- | --- |
| ServerId1 | 1 |
| ServerId2 | 2 |
| ServerId3 | 3 |
| ServerId4 | 4 |
| ServerId5 | 5 |
| ServerId6 | 1 |
| ServerId7 | 2 |
| ServerId8 | 3 |
| ServerId9 | 4 |
| ServerId10 | 5 |
| ServerId11 | 1 |
| ServerId12 | 2 |
| ServerId13 | 3 |

ServerType

| Id | ServerType |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Developer |
| 2 | Basic |
| 3 | Standard |
| 4 | Advanced |
| 5 | Premium |

`[dbo].[Servers].[ServerTypeId]` is a foreign key to the column `[dbo].[ServerTypes].[Id]`

I have a requirement to set the priority server for a serverType.

So I added a column `IsPriority` to Servers:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Servers]
ADD IsPriority BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

Does that violate any normalization rules?

Should I create a new table PriorityServers and add relations to the Server and ServerType table?

Comment: Please do not overrate "database normalization", see:  [Is database normalization dead?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19912/is-database-normalization-dead)

Comment: @Luuk The point of database normalization is to avoid 1. redundancy and 2. inconsistency. They are good rules of thumb, i.e., let's have atomic fields and avoid transitive functional dependencies, etc. These rules make sense, but sometimes they are put aside for other purposes, like performance necessities. As you pointed out, database normalization should be not followed blindly, but I would advocate that beginners should learn them and whenever we neglect them, we should do so with a good reason.

Comment: With the `IsPriority` attribute in the `Server` table, one can create a unique filtered non-clustered index on `ServerType` and `IsPriority` to ensure only one row of a given ServerType is the priority one: `CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx ON dbo.Server(ServerType, IsPriority) WHERE IsPriority = 1;`

Comment: @Luuk I read the question you mentioned. I fail to see the relationship between ORMs and normalization (for good or bad). One is just a tool to simplify database access, the other one defines how to design a database.

Comment: Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. How/where are you 1st stuck, following what published design method? [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Techincally speaking, proper database normalization would ask for a separate table. But enforcing uniqueness would get complicated, requiring two unique keys and two foreign keys.

Your existing solution is much easier. You just need to enforce that only one Server of each ServerType can exist at once. You can do this using a filtered unique index.

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_Server_ServerType ON dbo.Server
  (ServerType) INCLUDE (Id)
WHERE (IsPriority = 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

If `IsPriority` is a server attribute, then adding it does not violate normalization rules, because it's atomic and there is no transitive functional dependencies, i.e., FDs where the source is not the primary key.

You can enforce your only 1 prio per server type via a trigger or application code.

Alternatively you can add the `IsPriority` field to your server type table instead of the server table, but the problem would be that it would be less intuitive for humans and you would always need to join to server type in order to find out whether a given server is priority. It is doable that way as well though.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't enforce (by database constraints) that only one server can have priority. That woud require a reference back from ServerType to Server.

Comment: @GertArnold that's something that should be enforced either by a trigger or application code or something like that. I would not maintain this logic by rules.